# PC won't boot with 4 prong CPU connector connected. Motherboard or CPU dead - which one? Both?

Tags: cpu, motherboard

In the middle of use, my computer shut down. I tried to turn it on but it maybe comes on for half a second, shuts down, then flickers again very quickly about 2 seconds later before giving up completely.

So I took everything apart and nailed it down to the power supply, the mobo, or the CPU. I had an extra old power supply around, hooked that up and it had the same problems, so that can't be it.

When the 4 prong CPU connector is not connected, the motherboard 'functions' in that it stays on and runs the heat sink etc. Throw in the 4 prong connector and that's when it doesn't stay on.

So it must be the CPU, right?

Motherboard: ASUS P6X58D
CPU: Intel i7-920

Bot are under warranty (supposedly) - should I get both replaced or what?

Comment: It doesn't mean it is the processor, it could still be something on the motherboard pertaining to that socket. Motherboard issues are FAR more common than CPU issues, so I would lean toward a motherboard issue. Do you see any noticeable damage on the board - burn marks, damaged capacitors, etc?

Comment: I see no damage on the board itself, no.

Comment: Could be the power supply, motherboard *or* CPU.

Comment: @scrot, you’re not talking about the standby power connector are you?

Comment: Synetech - not sure? I'm not as versed as I was with the hardware when I built the machine about a year ago. It's the 4 prong connector from the PSU (or alternatively the 8 prong) that's supposed to power the CPU that exposes the problem.

Comment: Does the CPU cooling fan spin up? If you are taking the power off the CPU and the MB stays up then it may be that the CPU is overheating which is causing the MB to shut down

Comment: So I RMA'd the motherboard and it turned out to be bad. All working now. Thanks folks.